# How does background removal help reduce computation in CNN?

Tags: image-processing, convolution

I read in many papers that a preprocessing of background removal help reduce the amount of computation. But why is this the case? My understanding is that he CNN works on a rectangular window no matter how is it filled up, 0 or positive.

See [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05718.pdf) for an example.

Comment: Can you please provide a few links to some of these papers? Also, in which applications of CNNs (In the ones I know about - which are not numerous - , the entire image is important)

Comment: @Ash Added one at hand. I'll try to find more later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the paper you provide, it seems that they do not pass the entire image to the network. Instead, they seem to be selecting smaller patches from the non-white background. This makes sense because it reduces the noise in their data, but it also reduces computational complexity, because of the effect it has on fully connected layers.

Suppose the input image is of size `h*w`. In your CNN, the image passes through a series of convolutions and max-poolings, and as a result, right before the first fully connected layer, you end up with a feature map of size

```
sz=m*(h/k)*(w/d)
```

where `m` is the number of feature planes, and where `k` and `d` depend on the number of layers, the parameters of each convolution and max pooling modules (*e.g.* the size of the convolution kernel, etc). Usually, we'll have `d==k`. Now, assume that you feed this to a fully connected layer, to produce a vector of `q` parameters. What this layer does is basicaly a matrix multiplication

```
A*x
```

where `A` is a matrix of size `q*sz`, and `x` is just your feature map written as a vector.

Now, assume you pass a patch of size `(h/t)*(w/t)` to the network. You end up with a feature map of size

```
sz/(t^2)
```

Given the size of the images in their datasets, this is a considerable reduction in the number of parameters. Also, small patches also means larger batches, and that too can accelerate training (better gradient approximation.).

I hope this helps.

**Edit, following @wlnirvana's comment :** Yes, patch size is a hyper parameter. In the example I gave, it is set via selecting `t`. Given the size of the images in the dataset, I'd say something like `t>=6` would be realistic. As for how this relate to background removal, to quote the paper (section 3.1):

"To reduce computation time and to *focus our analysis on regions of the slide most likely to contain cancer metastasis*..."

This means that they select patches only around areas that are not background. This makes sense, since passing a completely white patch to the network would just be a waste of time (in figure 1, you can have so many white/gray/useless patches if you select them randomly, without removing the background). I didn't find any explanation on how patch selection is done in their paper, but I assume something like selecting a number of pixels `p_1,...,p_n` in the non-background regions, and considering `n` patches of size `(h/t)*(w/t)` *around* each of them would make sense.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why the patch size becomes `(h/t)*(w/t)`. I thought the patch size is a hyper-parameter solely determined by the programmer, and has nothing to do with background removal. Did I miss something?

Comment: To rephrase and confirm my understanding, background removal reduces computation actually by reducing the number of training patches?

Comment: I think that it is what allows training using patches in the first place. If you don't do background removal, then selecting patches will most likely provide you with losts of redundant data, and therefore, it would be better to train on the whole image (rescaled to a smaller size) instead. So, my understanding is that it reduces computional time *not* by reducing the number of patches, but by making a patch-based approach possible in the first place.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much.